# Is This How to Create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) with Entity Framework Core & ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2+ and 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dto

In creating a RESTful Api with ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 I noticed there wasn't a a DTO example like the 2014 web api example.

[ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 Rest api 2019 example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths)

[ASP.NET web-api 2014 example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

So, I decided to create DTO's for a few of my controller verbs HTTPGet, HTTPPost and HTTPPut

I have 2 fold questions from my final result.

1. Is this the recommended way of doing it in a general sense.  Or is there something in the new Entity Framework Core that is different or better than the 2014 example that was based on Entity Framework 6 or previous?
2. Should one utilize the DTO design pattern in general?  Or is there something in the Entity Framework Core that is different from a DTO pattern altogether.  Specifically is there a way to take data from a database and pass it to the view/client the exact way I need it to be passed over?

More background to the reason for asking question part 2.  I have read about DTO's being anti-patterns and people say don't use them for one reason or another.  However, many developers implore their usage and when and why they should be used.  A personal example for me is working and Angular and React projects. Receiving data I need is a beautiful thing that I can't imagine any other the other alternative which would be to do all types of hoops and parsing to get through a monolithic object to display address and location onto the screen.

But have times changed and is there a design pattern or another pattern that would do the exact same thing but at a lower expense and compute cost.

3. For that matter is there a great compute cost to the server and dbserver for using this pattern?
4. Lastly, is the code below how one would expect to utilize a DTO pattern in Entity Framework Core as opposed to the EF 6 or linq to sql frameworks?

I have included the code changes below to illustrate my DTO creation for the TodoItem model from the below exercise.

**Project(TodoApi) --> DTOs --> TodoItemDTO.cs:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItemDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public string Names { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsCompletes { get; set; }
    }

    public class TodoItemDetailDTO
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Names { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsCompletes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Project(TodoApi) --> Controllers--> TodoController.cs:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Models;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoController: ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                // Create a new TodoItem if collection is empty, 
                // which means you can't delte all TodoItems.
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Console.WriteLine(GetTodoItems());
        }

        // Get: api/Todo
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
        {
            var todoItems = await _context.TodoItems.Select(t =>
                        new TodoItemDetailDTO()
                        {
                            Id = t.Id,
                            Names = t.Name,
                            IsCompletes = t.IsComplete
                        }).ToListAsync();

            return Ok(todoItems);

            // previous return statement
            //return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
        }

        // Get: api/Todo/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TodoItemDetailDTO), 201)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
        {
            var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.Select(t =>
            new TodoItemDetailDTO()
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Names = t.Name,
                IsCompletes = t.IsComplete
            }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);

            if (todoItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(todoItem);

            //var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

            //////if (todoItem == null)
            //{
            //    return NotFound();
            //}

            //return todoItem;
        }

        // POST: api/Todo
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a TodoItem.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Sample request:
        ///
        ///     POST /Todo
        ///     {
        ///        "id": 1,
        ///        "name": "Item1",
        ///        "isComplete": true
        ///     }
        ///
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <returns>A newly created TodoItem</returns>
        /// <response code="201">Returns the newly created item</response>
        /// <response code="400">If the item is null</response>            
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TodoItemDTO), 201)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TodoItemDTO), 400)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
        {
            _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            _context.Entry(item).Property(x => x.Name);
            var dto = new TodoItemDTO()
            {
                Names = item.Name,
                IsCompletes = item.IsComplete
            };

            // didn't use because CreatedAtAction Worked
            // return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id }, dto);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = item.Id }, dto);

            // original item call for new todoitem post
            //return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }

        // PUT: api/Todo/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TodoItemDTO), 201)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TodoItemDTO), 400)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutTodoItem(long id, TodoItem item)
        {
            if (id != item.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var dto = new TodoItemDTO()
            {
                Names = item.Name,
                IsCompletes = item.IsComplete
            };

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = item.Id }, dto);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Todo/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteTodoItem(long id)
        {
            var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (todoItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.TodoItems.Remove(todoItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity creates classes in c# that map to a database.  The mapping only needs to be done once and not in code.  You can usually create the classes/mapping in VS using the menus.  The reference at the bottom of the 2014 link provided tools that do the mapping.  Since the mapping only need to be done once (or when the database table schema changes) I would recommend mapping to the database using the VS menus.

Comment: @jdweng not totally following I am new to C#. Can you provide an example of what you are saying.  The tool at the bottom of the page goes to a project that is geared towards EF6 so that is why I was hesitant to dive into that.  Also, what do you mean exactly by VS using the menus?

Comment: I was referring to the Auto Mapper which automatically creates the c# classes from a database.

Comment: @jdweng yes but that is for EF6 not EFCore and creating classes for each does exactly what? If I need to alter what is seens and or naming conventions how would that help exactly

Comment: EFCore is a light weight version of Entity.  The Mapping is Entity.  You cannot use both Entity and DTO.  See : https://www.driver733.com/2018/10/08/entity-and-dto.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're getting too hung up on semantics. Strictly speaking, an "entity" is merely an object with identity (i.e. has an identifier), in contrast to something like a "value object". Entity Framework (Core or no) is an object/relational mapper (ORM) that abstracts object persistence. The "entity" being fed to EF is a class that represents an object in the persistence layer (i.e. a row in a particular table). That is all.

However, as such, it's often not incredibly useful in other scenarios. The SRP (single-responsibility principle) pretty much dictates that the entity should concern itself only with the actual stuff that's important to persistence. The needs of a handling a particular request, feeding a particular view with data, etc. can and will diverge from that, meaning you either need to make the entity class do too much or you need additional classes specifically for those purposes. That's where the concept of things like DTOs, view models, etc. come into play.

In short, the correct thing to do is to use what makes sense in a particular circumstance. If you're dealing with a CRUD-type API, it might make sense to use the entity class directly in that scenario. However, more often than not, even in the scenario of CRUD, it's still usually preferable to have a custom class to bind the request body to. That allows you to control things like serialization and which properties are viewable, editable, etc. In a sense, you're decoupling the API from the persistence layer, allowing the two to work independently of each other.

For example, let's say you need to change the name of a property on your entity. If your API uses the entity directly, then that would require versioning the API and dealing with deprecation of the previous version with the old property name. Using a separate class for each, you can simply change the mapping layer and the API goes along happily unaware. No change is required by clients interacting with the API. As a general rule, you want to always pursue the path of least coupling between components.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From what I understand regarding your answer is that if it is necessary then it could be used... And the decoupling aspect is a benefit as well.  Can you elaborate on my question directly in addition to your response. This would help close out the question and be very useful for my inquiry if you don't' mind.  Also, systemantics at the end of the day are a lot of times how we understand something.

Comment: Here, semantics cloud the issue. At the end of the day, you have classes. What you call them is ultimately irrelevant. You could have an entity for persistence and an entity for HTTP transfer, and they don't necessarily need to be the same thing. Like I said, entity just means it has an identifier. Don't focus on the terms, focus on the needs of your application and good separation of concerns.

Comment: But the semantic is for all intents and purposes relates to a design pattern. A pattern not unlike the one you are describing.  Is the DTO design pattern the way you would accomplish this goal.  Is there a better design pattern.  I am looking for best practices in the C# world.  I recently was tasked with DTO's for a java project as it is a heavily used design pattern in java. I am not worried about the semantics at all. I simply am looking to abstract from the model and create a return to the view that is procured the way I want it. Im trying to get confirmation this is a good design pattern

Comment: Hi, I heard about some  php frameworks allow you to make dataanotation to your entity that  defines witch property should be visible in return. I believe they called it the serializer  and those data annotation serializer group. Does something similar exists in .Net or Core ?